# DHHTMLX 6.0 Grid/Treegrid not showing on Vue page

Tags: dhtmlx

I’m trying to import grid and init into page, but no luck and looks like nothing happened.

My source:

https://pastebin.com/LSSS3e5Q

I have installed Treegrid, also tried and with dhx-grid, dhx-suite:

npm i dhx-treegrid
npm i dhx-grid
npm i dhx-suite

What I see in developer tools, that in mine container, created new div element and that’s it:

```
<div class="dhx_grid"></div>
```

Anyone can help, what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Please add code to the question. If pastebin goes away, is unavailable or is otherwise inaccessible then the question won't have any context

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure that the sizes of your grid container are defined and applied correctly.

If the problem still occurs for you please, provide a complete demo or a demo link, where the problem can be reconstructed locally.